# Getting Room Name or Subject From Muc Hooks

Tags: erlang, xmpp, ejabberd, erl, ejabberd-hooks

I want to get the room's name or subject from one of the ejabberd hooks.
I've a method like in the below code and I want to get room's name or subject within that method.
Is something like that possible?

```
muc_filter_message(Stanza, MUCState, RoomJID, FromJID, FromNick) ->
    PostUrl = gen_mod:get_module_opt(FromJID#jid.lserver, ?MODULE, post_url, fun(S) -> iolist_to_binary(S) end, list_to_binary("")),
    Token = gen_mod:get_module_opt(FromJID#jid.lserver, ?MODULE, auth_token, fun(S) -> iolist_to_binary(S) end, list_to_binary("")),
    Body = fxml:get_path_s(Stanza, [{elem, list_to_binary("body")}, cdata]),

    _LISTUSERS = lists:map(
        fun({_LJID, Info}) ->
            binary_to_list(Info#user.jid#jid.luser) ++ ".."
        end,
        dict:to_list(MUCState#state.users)
    ),
    ?DEBUG(" #########    GROUPCHAT _LISTUSERS = ~p~n  #######   ", [_LISTUSERS]),

    _AFILLIATIONS = lists:map(
        fun({{Uname, _Domain, _Res}, _Stuff}) ->
            binary_to_list(Uname) ++ ".."
        end,
        dict:to_list(MUCState#state.affiliations)
    ),
    ?DEBUG(" #########    GROUPCHAT _AFILLIATIONS = ~p~n  #######   ", [_AFILLIATIONS]),

    _OFFLINE = lists:subtract(_AFILLIATIONS, _LISTUSERS),
    ?DEBUG(" #########    GROUPCHAT _OFFLINE = ~p~n  #######   ", [_OFFLINE]),

    if
        Stanza /= "", length(_OFFLINE) > 0 ->
            Sep = "&",
            Post = [
                "type=groupchat", Sep,
                "to=", RoomJID#jid.luser, Sep,
                "from=", FromJID#jid.luser, Sep,
                "offline=", _OFFLINE, Sep,
                "nick=", FromNick, Sep,
                "body=", url_encode(binary_to_list(Body)), Sep,
                "access_token=", Token
            ],
            ?INFO_MSG("Sending post request to ~s with body \"~s\"", [PostUrl, Post]),
            httpc:request(post, {binary_to_list(PostUrl), [], "application/x-www-form-urlencoded", list_to_binary(Post)},[],[]),
            Stanza;
        true ->
            Stanza
    end.
```

Thanks

Comment: any idea about the problem?

Comment: Can't you query muc_room table using RoomJID and pick room subject?

Comment: I dont know how can I do it with using erlang? I'm not familiar with erlang

Comment: check "mod_last.erl" file, it will be simplest example. It basically queries last seen time of user so it involves database interaction. Logic is also not that much complex.

Comment: Does mod_last.erl contain something about multi user chat rooms?

Comment: No, it doesn't contain any such thing.

Comment: so why did you suggested to me to look mod_last.erl file?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128514/discussion-between-shoaib-ahmad-gondal-and-tolgatanriverdi).

Comment: any different idea about the problem?

Comment: Nope, i searched in code but didn't find workaround. No specific database example to share with you.